# C warning: Pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ differ in signedness

Tags: c, printf, warnings, unsigned

I have the following piece of code that writes the value of `time` into the `temp` buffer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char temp[8];
    unsigned int time = 0x00101010;
    
    sprintf(temp, "%x", time);
}
```

Both `temp` and `time` are unsigned values; however, I still get the following warning:

```
Pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ differ in signedness
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting this warning and how to remove it?

Comment: `sprintf()` expects `char *` as first argument which can be - an in your case obviously is - signed by default

Comment: When dealing with strings, you generally want to use type `char` rather than `unsigned char`.  That's what all the library functions, like `sprintf`, want.

Comment: Which is 'argument 1 of `sprintf`'?  It's the `temp` string (which has very little margin for error in its sizing; the buffer should be bigger — at least 9 bytes long).  So the compiler is complaining about the type of `temp` as passed to `sprintf()`.   You should consider using `snprintf()`, not that changing to it will fix the compiler warning.  The explicit `unsigned char` and `signed char` types are both disadvantaged by the standard C library — there are no functions to support either, even though they're both distinct from plain `char` (but one of them is equivalent to plain `char`).

Comment: Additionally, 8 chars is not enough to hold hex string even for 4-byte integer, there is no space for null terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char temp[8];
    unsigned int time = 0x00101010;
    
    sprintf(temp, "%x", time);
}
```

or

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char temp[8];
    unsigned int time = 0x00101010;
    
    sprintf((char*) &temp, "%x", time);
}
```

sprintf is defined as `sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)`, so the first argument needs to be a signed char pointer.